# php pcntl_signal with proc_open

Tags: php, signals

I have a custom php script that opens a third party perl script using proc_open.  I was trying to put in some pcntl_signal handles so I could cleanup gracefully on an interrupt.

I'm able to get my signal handler to work in more confined test beds where it's just spinning in a loop or something.

However when it's looping through the child script w/ proc_open a CTRL+C seems to just completely die right there.  To be clear I mean complete immediate stopping of both the parent and child process.  It's *not* as if the ctrl+c is is being caught by the 3rd party child process, returning and my script continues.

I've read in the php docs it's known signal handling doesn't play well with things like sleep() and figured it might be something similar w/ the POSIX proc_open functions.  Looking over SO there seemed to be a few similar posts with a solution to either move signal handling in a child process or toggle the restart_syscalls param to proc_open, depending on the situation.

I've tried toggling the restart_syscalls param to false but that didn't do me any good.

Unfortunately the child process is a 3rd party script so I'm not familiar with the actual code.  Before trying to muck around in that to get signals propagated back up (if that's possible or even the thing to do) I was wondering if there's something missing with my setup that so I could maintain just my code.

What I have looks like

```
<?php

declare(ticks=1);

class signalHandler{

    public static function handle($signal){
        throw new KillException("Received Kill signal $signal", $signal);
    }

}
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,array('signalHandler','handle'));
```

Then later on, calling the actual child process:

```
$childCmd = "thirdPartyScript.pl";

// Set up how we'll interact with the IO file handlers of the process
$descriptors = Array(
    0 => Array('file', '/dev/null', 'r'), // Process will read from /dev/null
    1 => Array('pipe', 'w'), // Process will write to STDOUT pipe
    2 => Array('pipe', 'w')  // Process will write to STDERR pipe
);

// Start the process
$childProc = proc_open($childCmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

// Check the status of the backup every second...
$streamContents = '';

stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
do {
    $streamContents .= stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    if( ! ( $childStatus = proc_get_status($childProc) ) ) {
        throw new Exception("Error: Unable to retrieve status on child process.");
    }


} while ($childStatus['running']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to SIGCHLD too, if you want to be notified when your child dies.
I think that you can also put safely for example sleep(1) inside the polling cycle to reduce busy work.